# Twilio - Messaging Service Inbound Setting to Twilio Function instead of Webhook

Tags: twilio

I have a phone number that I configured the inbound messaging to run a Twilio function sends the message to the AWS SQS service.

But due to outbound traffic and other limitations, I setup a Messaging Service and I'm using the Passthrough API for bulk outbound.  But for the inbound configurations for the Messaging Service,  we are only limited to dumping the message, executing a webhook, or starting a conversation. I don't have the ability to run a Twilio function.

If I go back to the phone number configuration I can't have it both ways... it's either the Function or the Messaging Service.

Is there a way I can run a Twilio function on inbound messages to the Messaging Service or do I need to do this all in the webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you choose Function in the inbound configuration for a number, it is just setting up the number to point to the Function's webhook URL.

So, you can enter the Function URL as the webhook URL for your messaging service and you shouldn't need to change anything else.